# Copy activity with REST source and sink

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cognitive-search

Previewing the source in the [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) returns data inside an array.  Always.  Is this the expected behavior with REST datasets?  Use any online rest API like https://reqres.in and the preview yields an object not an array.

The copy activity does not support Azure Search as a source.

Paging over the [Azure Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) as a source and the [Azure Search Add, Update or Delete Documents API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) as a sink should be simple since no mapping is needed.

The response from **search** GET || POST (source) is an **object**:

```
{
  ...,
  "value": [ <search documents> ]
}
```

where the **value** property is an **array** of search documents.  The **upload** POST (sink) only needs an object with a **value** property of search documents since the default **@search.action** is **upload**.

Debugging the copy activity faults with:

```
An unexpected 'StartArray' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.
```

which implies that the body posted by the sink is an always array not an object.  Debugging does not show the posted body.

Here is a [link to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1164038/rest-sink-with-non-array-payload-(body)) the same question asked on Microsofts Q/A portal.

Comment: can you share sample input output?

Comment: Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/MatthewDavidCampbell/5f843c1e6896f98bb321d2b17706fce8) with the linked service, dataset, and pipeline definitions plus the input + output.  Paging is not a complete example instead hard-coded in the gists.  DataRead property (see output) is showing about 10 search documents at a size of 15892.

Comment: Renamed the non-working pipeline to 3.a. Pipeline and an example of a Search sink to 3.b. Pipeline which does work using a collection reference of **$.value**.  Shame string arrays aren't supported for Search sinks otherwise problem solved.

Comment: See Microsoft [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#tabularhierarchical-source-to-hierarchical-sink) about schemas: "When copying data from hierarchical source to hierarchical sink, you can additionally preserve entire layer's hierarchy, by selecting the object/array and map to sink without touching the inner fields." - How?

Comment: See [REST as a Sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory) section where Microsoft states the "data will be sent in JSON with the following pattern" and below an array is shown.  An assumption is that an array is either the default or only option even with hierarchical data inside an array element that can be subject to schema mapping.